# file rename script (move part of filename)

Tags: powershell, script

I have files names containing 2 `-`'s.

- Before the first the text is always the same (`daughter of moon`).
- After the first `-` (followed by a blank, and before the `-` it is also a blank) it is usually some number (but can also be some text).
- After the second `-` similar.

I want to split my filename in 3. `part1 - part2 - part3.jpg`.

I would like to have a script which moves `part3` to `part2` (= switch the parts).

Later I want to be able to switch some `part2` and `part1`.

I have tried things like

```
get-childItem 'daugther of moon - * - 2*.jpg' | rename-item -newname ` { $_.name -replace ($x.split('moon -')[0], $x.split(' - ^ - ')[1], $x.split('- 2')[2], $x.split('.')[3] -join)}
```

but that seem not to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, what you're asking isn't entirely clear. Can you provide some specific examples of before-and-after filenames?  Second, SuperUser isn't a script-writing service; you'll get better responses if you show your work - what have you tried, how has it failed, what error messages or erroneous output did you get?

Comment: To break this up, does `get-childItem 'daugther of moon - * - 2*.jpg'` pull the correct file list that you need?

Comment: yes the get-childItem 'daugther of moon - * - 2*.jpg' is giving me the correct list :
daugther of moon - anorexia nervosa - 230 en 231.jpg
daugther of moon - begrippenlijst - 270 en 271.jpg
daugther of moon - begrippenlijst - 272 en 273.jpg

Comment: should become : daugther of moon - 230 en 231 - anorexia nervosa.jpg
daugther of moon - 270 en 271 - begrippenlijst.jpg
daugther of moon - 272 en 273 - begrippenlijst.jpg

Comment: ex. of error : get-childItem 'dochters van de maan - * - 2*.jpg' |
rename-item -newname `{ $_.name -replace ($x.split('maan -')[0], $x.split(' - ^ - ')[1], $x.split('- 2')[2], $x.split('.')[3] -join)}
At line:1 char:184
+ ...  $x.split(' - ^ - ')[1], $x.split('- 2')[2], $x.split('.')[3] -join)}
+                                                                        ~
You must provide a value expression following the '-join' operator.
At line:1 char:185
+ ...  $x.split(' - ^ - ')[1], $x.split('- 2')[2], $x.split('.')[3] -join)}

Comment: (continued error message ) :  +                                                                         ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script uses a RegEx to build groups `()` from the elements divided by the `-` and rearranges them to build the new name

```
# Change path to fit your environment
Pushd "A:\"
Get-ChildItem 'daugther of moon - * - *.jpg' |
  Where BaseName -match '(daugther of moon) - (.*) - (.*)'|
    Rename-Item -NewName {$matches[1]+' - '+`
                          $matches[3]+' - '+`
                          $matches[2]+$_.Extension} -Confirm
PopD
```

As Rename-Item accepts piped input the script block `{}` assembles the elements in the new order.

Sample output on my `A:\` ramdrive

```
Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
      "Item: A:\daugther of moon - one - two.jpg 
Destination: A:\daugther of moon - two - one.jpg".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

Comment: just confirming this script did what it needed to do. Thanks

Comment: The best way to acknowledge a good answer is to vote up and/or check mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk Rename Utility (http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php, Freeware) can do what you are looking for, and more, although I do realize this is not answering your question regarding what you are doing wrong on PowerShell ... (I'd use it's RegEx functionality to achive your goal)

Comment: Powershell comes with RegEx capabilities, so why use a 3rd party tool?

Answer (score 0):

When doing more complicated operations, it is easier to follow if you break it down.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'daugther of moon - * - 2*.jpg'

$files | ForEach-Object {
    $parts = $_.BaseName.Split("-")
    $partOne = $parts[0].Trim()
    $partTwo = $parts[1].Trim()
    $partThree = $parts[2].Trim()

    Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$partOne - $partThree - $partTwo$($_.Extension)"
}
```

Comment: got an error saying "cannot create file which already exist" ... PS G:\> $files | ForEach-Object {
>>     $parts = $_.BaseName.Split("-")
>>     $partOne = $parts[0].Trim()
>>     $partTwo = $parts[0].Trim()
>>     $partThree = $parts[0].Trim()
>>
>>     Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$partTwo - $partOne - $partThree$($_.Extension)"
>> }
Rename-Item : Kan geen bestand maken dat al bestaat.
At line:7 char:5
+     Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$partTwo - $partOne - $partThree$($_.Ext ...

Comment: What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: G:\af\do\daugther of moon - 162 en 163 - smudgenritueel.jpg 
Destination: G:\af\do\daugther of moon - daugther of moon - daugther of moon.jpg".  The whatif shows that it want to rename all the files with the same. and using as newname partone - partone - partone, while it should be partTwo - partOne - PartThree.

Comment: I found out what was wrong :  the index of $part[0] was for each part 0 ... changed partTwo to index 1 ($parts[1]) and partThree to index 2.  And it worked fine.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: LotPings fixed my typo, it should work now.